# Loading mod_ilbc in FreeSwitch failed

Tags: linker, codec, freeswitch, libtool

I've successfully installed other FS modules before, but this one I cannot fix. I'll produce as many details as possible and this question may not be a FreeSwitch-specific question. Any general troubleshooting suggestions would be appreciated.

Environment is like below, and I'm using freeswitch-1.6.19 source.

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

$ ls /usr/lib64/ilbc2/ -lh
total 64K
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  16 Oct 24 20:18 libilbc.so -> libilbc.so.0.0.2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  16 Sep 18 18:03 libilbc.so.0 -> libilbc.so.0.0.2
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 64K Jun 23  2015 libilbc.so.0.0.2

$ nm -D /usr/lib64/ilbc2/libilbc.so
--- omitted many lines ----
0000000000007590 T ilbc_decode
0000000000007790 T ilbc_decode_init
0000000000007c30 T ilbc_encode
0000000000008f80 T ilbc_encode_init
--- omitted many lines ----
```

I took these steps to compile `mod_ilbc`:

1. Uncomment the line `codecs/mod_ilbc` in `modules.conf`
2. `./configure --prefix=/opt/freeswitch/`
3. `make`
4. `make install`
5. Modify `/opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/vars.xml` to add `iLBC@30i` to `global_codec_prefs`.
6. Start freeswitch.

Here are the evidences that I see things are going smoothly:

1. `make install` successfully installs mod_ilbc. The `make` process successfully detects `libilbc` and uses `libtool` to link. Outputs of `make install`, note the `-L/usr/lib64/ilbc2 -lilbc` part.

```
making install mod_ilbc
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/cenzhe.zhu/freeswitch-1.6.19/src/mod/codecs/mod_ilbc'
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/cenzhe.zhu/freeswitch-1.6.19/src/mod/codecs/mod_ilbc'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod" || /usr/bin/mkdir -p "/opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod"
 /bin/sh /home/cenzhe.zhu/freeswitch-1.6.19/libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   mod_ilbc.la '/opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod'
libtool: install: (cd /home/cenzhe.zhu/freeswitch-1.6.19/src/mod/codecs/mod_ilbc; /bin/sh /home/cenzhe.zhu/freeswitch-1.6.19/libtool  --silent --tag CC --mode=relink gcc -I/usr/include/uuid -I/home/cenzhe.zhu/freeswitch-1.6.19/src/include -I/home/cenzhe.zhu/freeswitch-1.6.19/src/include -I/home/cenzhe.zhu/freeswitch-1.6.19/libs/libteletone/src -fPIC -Werror -Wno-unused-result -fvisibility=hidden -DSWITCH_API_VISIBILITY=1 -DHAVE_VISIBILITY=1 -g -ggdb -DHAVE_OPENSSL -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/include/ilbc2 -g -O2 -avoid-version -module -no-undefined -shared -o mod_ilbc.la -rpath /opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod mod_ilbc_la-mod_ilbc.lo /home/cenzhe.zhu/freeswitch-1.6.19/libfreeswitch.la -L/usr/lib64/ilbc2 -lilbc -lssl -lcrypto )
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/mod_ilbc.soT /opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_ilbc.so
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/mod_ilbc.lai /opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_ilbc.la
libtool: finish: PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod
```

2. `mod_ilbc` is compiled properly. It expects symbols like `ilbc_decode` from `libilbc`. Analyzing `mod_ilbc.so`:

```
$ nm -D /opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_ilbc.so
--- omitted many lines ----
0000000000001060 T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
                 U ilbc_decode
                 U ilbc_decode_init
                 U ilbc_encode
                 U ilbc_encode_init
--- omitted many lines ----
```

3. Upon starting freeswitch, it tries to load the module using `dlfcn` but failed. Output of `freeswitch.log`:

```
2017-10-25 13:54:24.243208 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1528 Error Loading module /opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_ilbc.so
**/opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_ilbc.so: undefined symbol: ilbc_decode**
```

It appears to me that this is because freeswitch failed to link `/usr/lib64/ilbc2/libilbc.so`, but why? How to further troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems formulating the problem and writing it up do help solving it. Problem solved now.

In the beginning, I don't know which `libilbc` I would need, so I installed both by `sudo yum install ilbc-devel ilbc2-devel`. Later when things don't work, I came across this [issue](https://freeswitch.org/jira/browse/FS-10003) so I removed version 1 of it by `sudo yum remove ilbc-devel`. BUT THAT DIDN'T REMOVE THE LIBRARY FILE!

There still lies `/usr/lib64/libilbc.so.0.0.1` and `/usr/lib64/libilbc.so.0`, and freeswitch seeks `libilbc` from them. BANG!

Comment: One command I found useful to debug this kind of library linking problem is `ldd`. `ldd /opt/freeswitch/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_ilbc.so` would display the list of shared libraries needed to load your module.

Comment: @PhilippeSultan That's englightening. `ldd` actually goes through the linking process, so I could have seen that FS is trying to link to the outdated so file. Would come handy next time. Thanks